# inserting a node at the end of a singly linked list in java geeksforgeeks

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

This is a code I got from geeksforgeeks on inserting a node at the end of a singly linked list. I do not understand step four. Why is it making the new_node.next into null, when it should be null in the first place when it was not initialized when the new_node was created?

```
// Linked List Class 
class LinkedList 
{ 
    Node head;  // head of list 
  
    /* Node Class */
    class Node 
    { 
        int data; 
        Node next; 
           
        // Constructor to create a new node 
        Node(int d) {data = d; next = null; } 
    } 


    /* Appends a new node at the end.  This method is  
       defined inside LinkedList class shown above */
    public void append(int new_data) 
    { 
        /* 1. Allocate the Node & 
           2. Put in the data 
           3. Set next as null */
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data); 
      
        /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the 
               new node as head */
        if (head == null) 
        { 
            head = new Node(new_data); 
            return; 
        } 
      
        /* 4. This new node is going to be the last node, so 
             make next of it as null */
        new_node.next = null; 
      
        /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
        Node last = head;  
        while (last.next != null) 
            last = last.next; 
      
        /* 6. Change the next of last node */
        last.next = new_node; 
        return; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: By the way, the top part of the second chunk of the code is chopped off a little into the outside of the shaded block.

Comment: I was going to reformat the code, but it's a wee bit more broken than just not indented right.  I think the `append` method is outside the `LinkedList` class definition, but should be inside it. - But I'm not sure I should make that fix.

Comment: I agree with you @qwerty.  I think that assignment is unnecessary.

Comment: @querty - you need to indent ALL your code so that it formats correctly.  The "{}" tool will do that for you.

Comment: The `return` at the end is unnecessary as well.  - and there are two step #4s

Comment: The first step for also creates another new node, which is redundant.

Comment: Ha!  @DaveNewton, you're absolutely right!  I totally missed that!  In short, don't take this code as "a good example" of anything :)

Comment: Oh, now I see there was a whole bunch of more things wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the line:

```
new_node.next = null;
```

is unnecessary.  In fact, even the comments bear witness to this.  The step #3 comment and the second step #4 comment explain the same operation, and there's no way to do the latter without having done the former.

Another unnecessary step, a much more significant one, was noticed first by @DaveNewton and missed by me.  The line:

```
head = new Node(new_data);
```

that occurs when the list is empty, should be:

```
head = new_node;
```

preventing an extra useless allocation of a `Node` object.  Optionally, the line:

```
Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
```

could be moved below the `if` block, but that would duplicate code unnecessarily (but not effort).

The `return` statement at the very end of the code is also unnecessary.

Comment: I guess it was written by someone who is not too familiar with java.